# Converting Inline style sheet to an external style sheet

Tags: html, css

I have following SyleSheet in my file.

**CSS**

```
<table style="font-family:Comic Sans MS;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="width:1000px;height:30px;background-color:Gray;">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:200px;height:600px;background-color:Lime;">
            </td>
            <td style="width:800px;height:600px;background-color:Maroon;">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="width:1000px;height:30px;background-color:Olive;">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

What I want is to make an independent style sheet of a table above so that On different table I can apply that style sheet.Cut long story short I wanna convert my inline style sheet to an external style sheet.

I tried but since there are same td's that need to be styled differently that confused me.I know that **I can use a class attribute** but if there is other possibility please tell me.

Comment: you can also add many styles to one td

Comment: I think you need to [read this](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/styles.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below should do it:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/7LR2K/)

```
table{
    font-family:Comic Sans MS;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;
}
tr:nth-child(1) td{
    width:1000px;height:30px;background-color:Gray;
}
tr:nth-child(2) td:first-child{
    width:200px;height:600px;background-color:Lime;
}
tr:nth-child(2) td:last-child{
    width:800px;height:600px;background-color:Maroon;
}
tr:nth-child(3) td{
    width:1000px;height:30px;background-color:Olive;
}
```

You can use [nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-child), [first-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/%3afirst-child) and [last-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3alast-child)

Comment: Please explain a bit me about the monster nth-chile(x).

Comment: what if have 1000 childs lets say. then fist-child,second-child ...will  work?